# Rails throwing ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, pg

I recently added bootstrap-datepicker-rails. Now when I try to save a record and I do not enter a date, I receive the active record error above.  I have validations set up - why wont it throw a more user friendly error? How can I get this to provide a user friendly error? I am using rails 4.2.7 and ruby 2.3.1.

Comment: Would you add the model code here (the validations part) ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have only added database level not null validation.

Add model level validation as well and you will get well formatted error message

```
validates :date, presence: true
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I forgot that! I so thought that I had it there